# why pass null before allocating memory to sysctlbyname function ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a code to get the device information on which my app is running iOS. I have a issue on understanding the below code and its working.

```
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); // what is the use of null here
char *model = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Why I cannot remove sysctlbyname () call before malloc? If i tried to do the below, iam getting malloc error.

```
size_t size;
// HAVE REMOVED THIS LINE FROM ABOVE
// sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *model = malloc(size);
s.ysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man malloc`:

> The malloc() function allocates size bytes of memory and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.

If you remove the first `sysctlbyname` call:

```c
size_t size;
char *model = malloc(size);
```

How many bytes should `malloc` allocate? Do you know the size upfront? Nope.

`man sysctlbyname`:

> The size of the available data can be determined by calling `sysctl()`
>   with the `NULL` argument for `oldp`. The size of the available data will
>   be returned in the location pointed to by `oldlenp`.  For some operations,
>   the amount of space may change often. For these operations, the system
>   attempts to round up so that the returned size is large enough for a call
>   to return the data shortly thereafter.

The first part says that you'd like to call `hw.machine` syscall and that you're not interested in the actual value (`NULL`), but just the `size`. `&size` is pointer to your `size` variable.

```c
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); // Get just size
char *model = malloc(size); // Alloc required amount of memory
```

The second part says that you'd like to call `hw.machine` syscall and that you're interested in the actual value and the size.

```c
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

---

There're some issues with this code. I'd rewrite it in this way:

```c
- (NSString *)deviceModel {
    size_t size;

    // Get buffer size to allocate
    if (sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        // syscall failed, return nil or handle it your way
        NSLog(@"syscall hw.machine failed with error %d", errno);
        return nil;
    }

    // Allocate memory for syscall result
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"malloc failed with error %d", errno);
        return nil;
    }

    // Get the actual value
    if (sysctlbyname("hw.machine", buffer, &size, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        // syscall failed, return nil or handle it your way
        NSLog(@"syscall hw.machine failed with error %d", errno);
        // Buffer already allocated, free it to avoid leaks
        free(buffer);
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a NSString from C string
    NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Free memory, bytes were copied in the stringWithCString:encoding:
    free(buffer);

    return deviceModel;
}
```